# How do I open a BioExcess vmdf file in Ubuntu?

Tags: windows-7, ubuntu, security, encryption

I am using Windows 7 along with Ubuntu 11.10 with a Lenovo B560.

In windows I have BioExcess software which is provided with the operation system. BioExcess  provides the facility of keeping all your data in one secure drive which can be opened either using a password or using your fingerprint.

Now whenever I log into the Ubuntu system, I am not able to access that secure drive, but in the partition in which my secure drive data is saved by BioExcess software, there is a file with the extension `vmdf`. Its size is the same as of my secure partition in Windows.

How can I open this `vmdf` file in Ubuntu 11.10? Is there any software available for it? Or is there any implementation of BioExcess for it?

I surfed through internet but didn't find any implementation of BioExcess for Ubuntu.

Answer (score 0):

There is a [Linux version](http://www.egistec.com/products/bioexcess-linux.aspx) of BioExcess, contact the vendor for details on how to get it.